# Use an overlay network for standalone containers is throwing context deadline exceeded

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have 2 servers where I tryed to create 1 container in each one and tryed to connect them via an overlay network, the servers specs are the folowing ones:

Server 1

- Centos 7
- docker 17.06.1-ce

Server 2

- Centos 7
- Docker 18.09.3

I followed the guide of this [link](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-overlay/) (Use an overlay network for standalone containers), but when I executed the command `docker run -dit --name alpine2 --network test-net alpine` on server 2 it throws the error `docker: Error response from daemon: attaching to network failed, make sure your network options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded.`, Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update the version of docker of server 1 from 17.06.1-ce to 18.09.3 and later follow the same guide, now everything works great.